# Linux Centos 6.5 and Oracle linux11gR2 installation from Gallery

Tags: azure

i have application need to be install on linux Centos 6.5 and oracale  linux11gR2

for Example i can install  windows 2008 server with Sql 2008 r2 from the gallery

my question is can i  install  linux Centos 6.5 and oracle linux11gR2 in the same machine from gallery   like what i did in windows 2008 server with Sql 2008 r2

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If from gallery, then i believe no. It is the Microsoft gallery of the preconfigured and tested images. [You can make your own image and upload that](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-classic-create-upload-vhd/), and then you will be able to use the Gallery and your own image.